# Designing the look and feel of Groupon (and similar sites)

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, social-networking

I am looking to design web applications that look and feel similar to [Groupon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupon), [Twitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitter), etc. I need to stay in the Microsoft arena, since that's what our company developes. We have tried [Silverlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight), but I have not been too pleased. What should I do?

Comment: This is really vague... what has the technology used got to do with the visual design? What are the requirements? Is it specifically RIA?

Comment: RIA? Do you mean Rich Internet App? If so, yes, it is RIA. Requirements are ability to handle high traffic, social networking (friend connects, avatar etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter and Groupon are basically rich HTML/CSS/JavaScript applications on the front-end.  "Rich", because they heavily leverage [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) and [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) 2 & 3 and are highly interactive (through the use of JavaScript).

[ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) is a fine choice for powering such a website. Your team will need to be experts at:

1. Cross-browser, cross-device HTML. A social networking site also requires a level of support for low bandwidth users and definite support for different accessibility requirements.
2. A good JavaScript library (or libraries) such as [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery), [YUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_UI_Library), etc.
3. CSS 2 and CSS 3 (and [HTML 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) is around the corner).
4. Caching mechanisms for handling high traffic.
5. Asynchronous methodologies (JavaScript is fine) for presenting interactive, dynamic content.

Comment: Is asp.net supposed to do the cross-browser compatibility? I am curious, how does asp.net perform in corss browser compatibility (since I have only worked with IE)?

Comment: ASP.Net has very granular support for detecting different browsers. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/browsercaps.aspx.  Most of the standard web controls provided with ASP.Net will output decent HTML that will work in any modern browser. However, it will be up to you to make your style sheets and scripts work in the browsers you wish to support.